# Android Studio: Place logcat below debug window

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, window, logcat

Does anyone know if it's possible to place the logcat-window below the debug-window in android studio ?

Placing the logcat and debugging-window next to each other is no solution, there's too little space. My solution is to place the logcat-window above the code editor, but I don't like that arrangement.

Current state:

[image: current]

Desired state:

[image: current]

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do it as well and I couldn't.
My "solution" when I need that configuration is to remove the logcat from AndroidStudio window using the "Floating Mode", and using a configuration with my Windows Manager "BetterSnapTool" this is the result. Not exactly what you and I wanted but it works for me. I hope this helps you.

[My "solution"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d12I.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

you can side by side for panels bottom right
[image]